# Updating drop down from json message, code not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery

my json response is

```
["Day", "Week"]
```

and the jquery which is supposed to run is

```
 $("#id_granularity").click(function(event)
    {

            event.preventDefault();
            var $form1=$('#dashboardForm')
            var $success2 = function(data)
            {
                    $("id_granularity").empty();


                    $.each(data,function(i,value)
                    {
                            alert("hello");
                            $("id_granularity").append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value',value));
                    });
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
                    beforeSend: function(xhr,settings) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken',csrftoken);
                    }
            });
                    var dposting = $.post("/grain", $form1.serialize(), $success2, "json");
            });
```

the event occurs but the dropdown is not updating or new items are not getting appended to

```
id_granularity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all instances of `$("id_granularity")` to `$("#id_granularity")` and see how that goes

Comment: usually just takes a second set of eyes sometimes. Good luck!